# Declaration Expected Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to read an rss feed in asp.net. I found the follow code to get me started. the line:

```
 WebRequest request=WebRequest.Create("myfeedurl");
```

Returns the error "Declaration Expected." I can't for the life of me figure out what could be wrong or what Declaration Expected means. Any help would be greatly appreciated I posted everything I have in the section below.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %> 
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script runat="server"> 
WebRequest request=WebRequest.Create("myfeedurl");
WebRequest response=request.GetResponse();

Stream rssStream=response.GetResponseStream();
XMLDocument xmlDoc=new XMLDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(rssStream);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are trying C# code in VB.Net.**

Your code should be:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("myfeedurl")
```